# PLSQL - Store a select query result in variable throw error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I want to store a select query result in a variable in PLSQL.

```
SQL>var v_storedate VARCHAR2(19);
SQL>exec :v_storedate := 'select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002'';
```

As

```
SQL>select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';
```

Returns : 2013/04/27-10:06:26:794

But it throws error:

```
 ERROR at line 1: ORA-06550: line 1, column 121: PLS-00103: Encountered
 the symbol "YYYY" when expecting one of the following:
 * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between ||
 multiset member SUBMULTISET_ The symbol "*" was substituted for "YYYY"
 to continue. ORA-06550: line 1, column 148: PLS-00103: Encountered the
 symbol ") and ryg=" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & =
 - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between
```

Comment: This `where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS')` doesn't make sense. `where a between b and c` works as `where a >= b and a <= c`. Your condition is always true. Can you describe what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Are you trying to put the query string into that variable, or the result of the query? The size of the variable suggests the latter (though it's still too small if you're expecting the `:794` part, which also implies `cdate` is a `timestamp`).

Comment: I tried to put the result of the query in the variable. Yes I got where the issue, I tried with VARCHAR2(255) and now it stopped throwing error, as it was storing the whole query in the variable. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to store the *result* of the query then you need to use a `select ... into`; at the moment you're trying to store the text of the actual query, not its result. If you wanted to do that you would need to escape the single-quote characters as the other answers have pointed out, and increase the variable size.

```
var v_storedate VARCHAR2(19);
exec select cdate into :v_storedate from rprt where cdate between cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';
print v_storedate
```

Which would be easier to deal with using a normal anonymous block rather than SQL*Plus' `execute` shorthand. You should also give an explicit date format mask when converting it to a string:

```
begin
    select to_char(cdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS')
    into :v_storedate
    from rprt
    where cdate between cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS')
    and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';
end;
/
```

If you want the fractional seconds then you need to make your variable bigger, as 19 chars will only take you to the seconds.

Either way though you're risking getting either multiple results (which will give `ORA-02112`) or no results (which will give `ORA-01403`). As your `where` clause doesn't make much sense and the table contents aren't known I don't know which is more likely. As be here now pointed out your `cdate` comparison is always going to be true, plus you're doing an implicit date conversion in there which will break at some point. There isn't enough information to fix that for you.

---

You can't get fractional seconds from a date value anyway, only from a timestamp; which `cdate` seems to be. But even then the format element for that is FF[0-9]. SSSSSS is the number of seconds since midnight. But as the whole `to_char()` bit looks wrong that's somewhat moot. Also, if you really do need a comparison with the current time, you should probably be comparing with `systimestamp` rather than `sysdate` to be consistent - and then not doing any conversion of that.

---

If you only want the date part:

```
var v_storedate VARCHAR2(10);
begin
    select to_char(cdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
    into :v_storedate
    ...
```

You can still use `exec` if you want to, but it's less readable once the statement gets longer than your terminal line length:

```
var v_storedate VARCHAR2(10);
exec select to_char(cdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') into :v_storedate from ... where ... ;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my  mistake. I need another suggestion,As the query results the value : `2013/04/27-10:06:26:794` as stored in the table. But I want only the date `2013/04/27` as my result to use the variable in other operation. Can that be possible in that single line ??

Comment: @PDK What do you mean by "I need another suggestion"? AlexPoole showed you how to fo fix the problem you posted - if you have another problem, please post a separate question.

Comment: @Alex Unable to declare variable as a date datatype.

Comment: "cdate between cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS')" looks to me like "cdate <= sysdate"

Comment: @PDK - sorry, I'd forgotten how restrictive [`variable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) is; updated to remove the `date` references.

Comment: @Alex if I am changing the date format from 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS' to any other format it started throwing error : `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 2
`

Comment: @David. Thank you for the suggestion. It shortened my query.

Comment: @PDK - changing it where - in the `select`, or the 'between`, if you still have that; what exactly are you running to throw that error?

Comment: @AlexPoole `var v_storedate VARCHAR2(140);
begin
      select to_char(cdate,'YYYY/MM/DD')
      into :v_storedate
      from rprt
      where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
      and ryg='R' AND CNUM='C002';
end;
/`

Comment: @PDK - I thought you'd changed to use David's suggestion. Why are you doing `to_char` on `sysdate`? If `cdate` is of type `DATE` then it'll just be converted back using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which might be where this error is coming from. You still haven't said what your `where` clause is supposed to be achieving.

Comment: @Alex cdate is VARCHAR2 data type, so its not converting.As david said,  I changed the query to `select cdate from rprt where cdate <= TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002';
`

Answer (score 4):

In PL/SQL a better approach to literals with single quotes in them is the quotation syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CBJJDDCG

```
begin
  variable := q'#select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002'#'
  ...
end
```

... or with matching delimiters ...

```
begin
  variable := q'[select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' and cnum='C002']'
  ...
end
```

You might try that in SQL*Plus also ... not sure if it works there.

Comment: `BEGIN :v_storedate := q'#select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' AND CRNUM='C002'#'; END;`
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
`BEGIN :v_storedate := q'[select cdate from rprt where cdate between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS') and ryg='R' AND CNUM='C002']'; END;`
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: What do you think that error means? "character string buffer too small"? How did you define :v_storedate?

Answer (score 0):

Escape your inner apostrophes by doubling them!

Comment: After doubling them its giving the below error:ERROR at line 1:
    **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string     buffer too small
    ORA-06512: at line 1**

Comment: SQL>var v_storedate VARCHAR2(19);

Change Above line to

SQL>var v_storedate VARCHAR2(140);

Answer (score 0):

- Double the inner apostrophes.
- And Change `Data Type` of `v_storedate` to `VARCHAR2(140);`

Comment: `SQL> var v_storedate VARCHAR2(140);
    SQL>  exec :v_storedate := 'select cdate from rprt where cdate    between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, "YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS") and ryg="R" and cnum="C002"';`
_BEGIN :v_storedate := 'select cdate from rprt where date between  cdate AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, "YYYY/MM/DD-HH24-MI-SS-SSSSS") and ryg="R" and cnum="C002"'; END;_
**
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1**

Comment: @PDK - 'double' is an unfortunate term here; 'doubling' doesn't mean using double-quotes (`"`), it means using two single quotes (`''`) to escape them. David's syntax is a bit easier to use and understand though.

Comment: @Alex I also tried with doubling the quotes `('')` and got the same result.